# Changes to copy dataframe changing original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have used df.copy() plenty of times and from time to time I've noticed this being an issue, and I've usually just made simple changes to counter this problem, but I really want to understand why making changes to a copy dataframe is changing my original dataframe. Below is a simple example of what I'm doing.

```
df = pd.read_excel(...)
x = df.copy()
x.columns.values[1:] = x.columns.values[2:-1]
```

Changing the column values in the 3rd line is changing the column values in df. I've tried df.copy(deep=True), but that's default anyways so if anyone's had issues with this, I'd really like to understand why this is happening, and if there's anything I can do to fix it.

Comment: Not able to duplicate this. Attach some screenshots or try `copy.deepcopy()`

Comment: I didn't include reproducable code because 1. I'm reading an excel file so don't know. I could create a dictionary (d) and do pd.DataFrame(d), but I highly doubt my issue would be reproduced... which is why I'm asking from more of a conceptual perspective. And I can't share code/data for work reasons unfortunately

Comment: Also, I tried df.copy.deepcopy() and got the following error: 'function' object has no attribute 'deepcopy'

Comment: I meant `from copy import deepcopy`. You can use a normal sample dataframe with random values to show how you're using `df.copy()`